# Disable Twig compilation cache for a particular template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Is there a way to disable the Twig compilation cache for a particular template?

I'm using Twig for my email templates. When someone updates these templates, they are written to disk. Although in production, I should clear the entire cache otherwise the updates aren't noticed.

That's why I want to disable the Twig cache for these particular templates. I don't mind the extra processing power, as clearing my entire cache is a bigger performance hit.

Comment: Why would you want to go this route?  If you can give us more context on why you would need this, we might be able to offer an alternate solution.  If what you are asking is possible (which it could be, but I don't know how), you're going to lose out on processing time when every request for that twig template has to parse and load it.

Comment: I can't answer your original question off hand, but I can point you to the bundle I use for handling e-mail templates: https://github.com/getme/EmailTemplateBundle .. That should help you fix your issue.

Comment: Too bad the Doctrine loader doesn't support inheritance. I'm still open for my initial question suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your answer might be not in disabling cache for a specific template, but clearing the cache for a template after it's been updated.  I haven't tested the code below, but it seems reasonable.  Play around with it a bit

In your action/service that saves a template (after the template has been saved):

```
$fileCache = $this->container->get('twig')->getCacheFilename('AcmeDemoBundle:Default:index.html.twig');

if (is_file($fileCache)) {
    @unlink($fileCache);
}
```

For more information, check out how twig cache files are handed in /vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php (\Twig_Environment) -- method loadTemplate().