# Render one Twig template without cache

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Our Symfony project has a login widget, which I was told should loaded via AJAX so as not to mess with page caching.

It displays either 'Log In', or the users email address if he is already logged in.

The problem is, that twig template is also cached! So loading it via ajax didn't help.

How can I tell Twig to render my template from scratch every time, without disabling cache site wide?

The template itself if very simple:

```
    <small id="login-username">
        {% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
            {{ app.user.username }}
        {% else %}
            {{ 'LoginWidgetElement.login' | trans }}
        {% endif %}
    </small>
```

The element's class is also very simple:

```
<?php

namespace Xyz\Sports\Element\LoginWidget;

use Xyz\Library\AbstractElement;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration as Config;

/**
* @Config\Template("@LoginWidgetElement/login_widget.html.twig")
*/
class LoginWidgetElement extends AbstractElement
{
    public function render()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function renderPreview()
    {
        return $this->render();
    }
}
```

> UPDATE

The twig template seems to be checking, therefore I tried sending a response telling the browser not to cache, but it still takes about 15 requests before the variable changes!!??

Twig cache:

```
<small id=\"login-username\">
            ";
        // line 9
        if ($this->extensions['Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\SecurityExtension']->isGranted("ROLE_USER")) {
            // line 10
            echo "                ";
            echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, twig_get_attribute($this->env, $this->source, twig_get_attribute($this->env, $this->source, (isset($context["app"]) || array_key_exists("app", $context) ? $context["app"] : (function () { throw new Twig_Error_Runtime('Variable "app" does not exist.', 10, $this->source); })()), "user", array()), "username", array()), "html", null, true);
            echo "
            ";
        } else {
            // line 12
            echo "                ";
            echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, $this->extensions['Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\TranslationExtension']->trans("LoginWidgetElement.login"), "html", null, true);
            echo "
            ";
        }
        // line 14
        echo "        </small>
```

So there is a `isGranted('ROLE_USER')` check. Now, in my render method:

```
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
$response->headers->set('Pragma', 'no-cache');

$body = $this->twig->render('@LoginWidgetElement/login_widget.html.twig');
$response->setContent($body);

return $response;
```

Still no cigar however :'-(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234464/disable-twig-compilation-cache-for-a-particular-template

Comment: thanks fucethebads, but that method has been deprecated and removed ;-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like setting cache headers has it's own method, and we shouldn't just use `$response->headers->set($key, $val);`

I moved the logic into a reusable trait:

```
<?php

namespace Xyz\Library\Traits;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

trait NoCacheHeadersTrait
{
    public function disableBrowserCache(Response $response) : Response
    {
        $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('no-store', true);
        $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('no-cache', true);
        $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('must-revalidate', true);
        $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('max-age', 0);
        $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('post-check', 0);
        $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('pre-check', 0);
        $response->headers->set('Pragma', 'no-cache');

        return $response;
    }
}
```

And now I `use` the trait in the class, and in my render method it now looks like this:

```
public function render()
{
    $response = $this->disableBrowserCache(new Response());
    $body = $this->twig->render('@LoginWidgetElement/login_widget.html.twig');
    $response->setContent($body);

    return $response;
}
```